# Spring State machine not accepting multi events from same transition

Tags: spring, state-machine

I am using Spring State Machine to implement my state machine, but I have encountered an issue during the usage.

Events: `E1`,`E2`,`E3`,
States: `S1`,`S2`,`S3`,

I want to transition from S1 to S2, and both events E1 and E2 can trigger this transition. Additionally, I need to evaluate the conditions for the transition based on data attached to events E1 and E2. Therefore, I only need `event -> action` mappings without any additional `entry/exit -> actions`. So, pseudo-states like Choice and Junction seem to be of little use to me. Currently, I handle it by defining two transitions: `Transition 1: S1 -> E1 -> S2`, `Transition 2: S1 -> E2 -> S2`. If I have five events, I would need to configure five transitions in this way.

Some code snippets like this:

```
transitions.withExternal()
                .source(VsimStatus.AVAILABLE).target(VsimStatus.RELEASE_SUCCESS).event(VsimCommandEvent.RELEASE_VSIM).guard(context -> condition1())
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(VsimStatus.AVAILABLE).target(VsimStatus.RELEASE_SUCCESS).event(VsimCommandEvent.REAPPLY_VSIM).guard(context -> condition2()
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(VsimStatus.AVAILABLE).target(VsimStatus.RELEASE_SUCCESS).event(VsimCommandEvent.TIMEOUT).guard(context -> condition3())
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(VsimStatus.AVAILABLE).target(VsimStatus.RELEASE_FAIL).event(VsimCommandEvent.RELEASE_VSIM).guard(context -> condition4());
```

Is there a better approach for this?